# Grab AVG score of the highest score for each test

Tags: sql, oracle, max, average

I'm having an issue writing a query that grabs/calculates the average of three test scores for specific tests for a student. Consider the following TEST_SCORES table:

```
ID   Name   TestCode  Score
-----------------------------
119  Joe       MCA      108  
119  Joe       BRT      98
119  Joe       LPO      76
119  Joe       BRT      111
119  Joe       ALK      83
119  Joe       MCA      100
119  Joe       RTK      75

For my scenario, I only want to consider scores from the "MCA" test, 
the "BRT" test, and the "RTK" test. I need the average of those tests. 
Also, I want to take the highest grade received for those 
tests (This is where I get stuck at). The following is what I have
so far:

SELECT A.ID, avg(A.Score)
FROM TEST_SCORES A
WHERE A.TestCode in ('MCA','BRT','RTK')
AND A.ID = 119
GROUP BY A.ID
```

There are more than one score entry for this student for the "BRT" test and the "MCA" test. I am trying to grab the MAX test score for each test. I try to use a condition to grab the max score, but I keep ending up with the highest test score period as opposed to the average of the three tests.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the expected result and tag the database being used?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Sounds like you just want to group by testcode, too, though. You know, you can group by multiple columns, right?

Comment: indeed, group by id, testcode should do the trick.

Comment: In this case, the expected result would be the ID and the average score all on one row. THe average would be 98 (108 + 111 + 75) / 3  ... Oracle database

Comment: Because there are multiple scores for the "MCA" test and the "BRT" test, how would I grab the highest score>? I'm thinking I'd need a MAX function in there somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `max` score per ID,testCode first and then `avg` those scores per ID.

```
SELECT ID,AVG(maxScore) as avgScore
FROM (SELECT ID,TestCode,MAX(Score) as maxScore
      FROM TEST_SCORES
      WHERE TestCode in ('MCA','BRT','RTK') 
      GROUP BY ID,TestCode
     ) t
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. This was driving me crazy. Something so simple too..sigh

Answer (score 0):

The setup is not optimal (the NAME shouldn't appear in this table, it should be in a smaller lookup table associating a name to each ID as shown in the illustration below).

Other than that, depending on your Oracle version, which you should always include in your question, you may or may not be able to use the `lateral` clause (available since Oracle 12.1) for a more efficient solution, in a single pass over the data - even if you need the average score for all students, not just for a single one.

Another observation though - if a student didn't take one of the exams (exam codes) at all, that exam will not be considered in the computation AT ALL, instead of getting averaged in with a score of 0 (as is usually the case in real life). The Accepted Answer doesn't handle that possibility, and neither does the solution below. **If that must be handled** then you need to clarify your question/requirement.

```
with
     test_data ( id, testcode, score ) as (
       select 119, 'MCA', 108 from dual union all 
       select 119, 'BRT',  98 from dual union all
       select 119, 'LPO',  76 from dual union all
       select 119, 'BRT', 111 from dual union all
       select 119, 'ALK',  83 from dual union all
       select 119, 'MCA', 100 from dual union all
       select 119, 'RTK',  75 from dual union all
       select 200, 'ABC', 110 from dual union all
       select 200, 'LPO',  90 from dual union all
       select 200, 'BRT',  90 from dual union all
       select 200, 'ALK', 102 from dual union all
       select 200, 'LPO',  90 from dual
     ),
     students ( id, name ) as (
       select 119, 'Joe' from dual union all
       select 200, 'Ann' from dual
     )
select s.id, s.name, avgscore
from   students s,
       lateral ( select   avg(max(score)) as avgscore
                 from     test_data t
                 where    t.id = s.id
                   and    testcode in ('MCA','BRT','RTK')
                 group by testcode
               )
;

 ID  NAME  AVGSCORE
---  ----  --------
119  Joe         98
200  Ann         90
```